# Insert characters at end of filename (before extension)?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have image files that I want to append a string to the name of the file, right before the extension.

Example: `example.png` would turn in to `example-2x.png`

So, I want to insert `-2x` right before the extension, would could be just about any image type (png, jpg, gif, etc).

If there's an easy way to do this with Ruby, great.

Comment: So how does your regex or attempt currently look? :)

Answer (score 10):

Rake has a nice [string extension](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/String.html) for manipulating paths:

```
require 'rake/pathmap'

"images/example.png".pathmap "%X-2x%x"
#=> "images/example-2x.png"
```

From [`pathmap`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/String.html#method-i-pathmap)'s docs:

> - **%X** -- Everything **but** the file extension.
> - **%x** -- The file extension of the path. An empty string if there is no extension.

Comment: At least in Ruby 2.7 `require 'rake/ext/string'` instead

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work

```
img[/(\.\w+)/] = "-2x#{$1}"


img1 = 'foo.png'
img1[/(\.\w+)/] = "-2x#{$1}"
img1 #=> "foo-2x.png"


img2 = 'foo.bar.jpg'
img2[/(\.\w+)/] = "-2x#{$1}"
img2 #=> "foo-2x.png.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use basename and extname to extract the two parts you want:

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-basename
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-extname

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```ruby
def insert_before_last_dot(str, part)
  idx = str.rindex('.')
  return str if (idx.nil? || idx==0)
  str.clone.tap { |x| x[idx] = part.to_s + '.' }
end

insert_before_last_dot('foo.jpg', '-2px') # => "foo-2px.jpg"
insert_before_last_dot('foo.bar.jpg', '-2px') # => "foo.bar-2px.jpg"
insert_before_last_dot('foo') # => "foo"
```

Comment: `insert_before_dot('foo.bar.baz.jpg', '-2px') # => "foo-2px.bar-2px.baz-2px.jpg"`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing that seems to work pretty well across pretty much any file type.

```
image = 'example.png'
ext = File.extname(image)
image_2x = image.gsub(ext, "-2x"+ext)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know ruby myself, but I would expect that there is some sort of `string.lastIndexOf()` like in java. So you basically just find the last dot, split the string around that, and then reconcatinate it with the `-2x`

Comment: That could become buggy: something based on that with a hidden file with no extension as input would return garbage as output.

Comment: Does ruby not have exception handling? I mean if you are really worried about that, you can just get if the `lastIndexOf()` returns a -1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in a Linux environment, the `rename` function should work.

```
rename {,\-2x,*}.png
```

In tcsh and bash shells this expands to `rename .png \-2x.png *.png`

Answer (score 0):

```
> "example.png".gsub /\.[^\.]*$/, "-2x\\0"
=> "example-2x.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that all of the above answers are more proper than mine but i find it effective to use the replace function...

Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace ".pdf"," - 2012.pdf"}

So you just take the file extension .png and replace it with -2x.png

this should work with any file extension as you are just replacing it with the same or even a different file extension and add whatever text you want before the file extension.